# Django - How to return to default image after users delete their uploaded image?

Tags: django, django-models, imagefield

So I originally had the user create a post in admin and be able to leave image field blank and Django would set a default image.

My problem is;
If a user uploads an image, then deletes the image in admin, I get an error: `The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it.` when accessing solo.html in browser.

How can I make the default image reappear and specifically come from static folder?
[image: Static folder location]

My code:

## settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_DIRS = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

## models.py

```
# FIXME: If default image is changed to user's upload but then deleted. Make default image reappear.
# Recipe Field
class Recipe(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)


    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='recipes/images/', blank=True)
    def get_image(self):
        if not self.image:
            return f'{settings.STATIC_URL}default.png'
        return self.image.url
```

## solo.html

```
<h2>{{ recipe.title }}</h2>
<h3>{{ recipe.category }}</h3>
<h3>{{ recipe.meal }}</h3>



<img src="{{ recipe.image.url }}">
```

I'm just starting with Django so I apologize in advance if it's all a mess.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: How are you deleting the recipe's image?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention, as of right now,  checking the clear box  in admin removes the images that I (user) uploads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that the file itself is being deleted, but `recipe.image` is not being set to `None`.

Comment: Recipe.image in template file or in ImageField in models?

Comment: The `Recipe` instance's `image` field. You can verify that this is a problem by opening up a shell, fetching the recipe that has the image deleted and running `bool(recipe.image)`. It should return True. But when you run `print(recipe.image.url)` it'll raise the exception.